# Flutter App crashes after sharing to another phone with no error

Tags: flutter, dart-html

I debug my flutter app successfully but after sharing it to a different phone using Xender the app couldn't be install. What can  be the problem? PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to share the release version of the app (Android: Signed APK; iOS: Archive) not the debug version. The debug version won't run standalone.

See https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android and https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios

Comment: Thanks. meaning I can not share the app in the debug mode.